# find xpath for a repeated angularJs Item

Tags: selenium, firefox, junit

how is possible to find the xpath for an angularJs element? for instance i discovered that all links in my page have the same xpath due to the repeated items in angularJs -->

```
.//*[@id='div_1_1_1_2']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a
```

but i  have 10 of  element , they are differente for text, so i tried with `"

so i tried with contains but it never find it

```
.//[@id='div_1_1_1_2']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[contains(@aria-label='Creazione Prodotto')]"`
```

i use selenium, junit4 , firefox webDriver

this is my code

```
public class PB01_TTT {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
  WebElement element;




    @Before()
      public void setUp() throws Exception {

    FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);

    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/octet-stream");
    fxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(fxProfile);
    baseUrl = "https://w8aon2bpm.replynet.prv:9443";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }




     @Test
      public void testPBO1TTT() throws Exception {

            driver.get(baseUrl + "/ProcessPortal/login.jsp");
          //    driver.get(baseUrl + "/ProcessPortal/dashboards/SYSRP/RESPONSIVE_WORK");

            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");





            String columnToDisplay=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='div_1_1_1_2']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[contains(@aria-label='Creazione Prodotto')]"));


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



                   element = (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.xpath(columnToDisplayXpath));

                   Assert.assertNotNull(element);
```

it always return me a notFoundElement, any suggestions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 links, then there is a high chance they are different in a way even if the path is the same, in this case you need to construct an path based on the thing that is different. 
For example: use href, text or other any part that differs

```
//a[contains(@href, 'part_of_href')]
//a[contains(text(), 'part_of_text')]
//a[@title='title']
//a[contains(@aria-label='Creazione Prodotto')]
```

If you need any help in getting the selector please add the html section of the links, you can change the url if needed.

> Tip: avoid using absolute xpaths and attributes that do not suggest anything and they can change like: `.//*[@id='div_1_1_1_2']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[contains(@aria-label='Creazione Prodotto')]"`
>   This will give you a lot of work in the future.